# stdout and stdin relationships

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does reading from stdin flush stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528/does-reading-from-stdin-flush-stdout)

C++ Standard guarantees that all data contained in the buffer will be printed before next call to std::cin. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void bar()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: "; /* 1 */
    std::cin >> x; /* 2 */
}
```

Because of this:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

> 27.4.2 Narrow stream objects [narrow.stream.objects]
>
> 2 After the object cin is initialized, cin.tie() returns &cout. Its
>   state is otherwise the same as required  for basic_ios::init
>   (27.5.5.2).
>
> 27.4.3 Wide stream objects [wide.stream.objects]
>
> 2 After the object wcin is initialized, wcin.tie() returns &wcout.
>   Its state is otherwise the same as  required for
>   basic_ios::init (27.5.5.2).

But in C there are really no guarantees that everything contained in the stdout buffer will be printed before any attempt to stdin?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter an integer: "); /* 1 */
    scanf("%d", &x); /* 2 */
}
```

I know that stdout is line buffered but i don't want to put '\n' character in such situations. Is using fflush / fclose / etc is the only right way to get output right before input request in C?

Comment: If your question is about C (and not about using stdio in C++), please tag it with C and not C++.

Comment: I've added tag C but this question is about C and C++ IO comparison, so i would like to keep C++ tag also.

Comment: Oh, it's been a while since a question here sparked my interest. I had never really payed attention to `tie`, I'll be watching this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no such guarantees.
Yes, you may use fflush() to ensure that stdout is flushed.

This question is closely related: [Does reading from stdin flush stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528/does-reading-from-stdin-flush-stdout)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know the cin / cout relation in C++, thank you.
In C, I don't know other way to flush the stdout buffer. I always use **fflush** when I need to be sure that the output has been printed at a given time.