# Why doesn't Haskell sequence these IO actions properly?

Tags: haskell

A friend of mine asked me why was I learning Haskell. To demonstrate the power of Haskell I wrote a small program which displayed a list of prime numbers:

```
main = do
    putStr "Enter the number of prime numbers to display: "
    number <- fmap read getLine :: IO Int
    print . take number . filter isPrime $ [2..]

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = not . any ((== 0) . mod n) $ [2..floor . sqrt . fromInteger $ n]
```

The program works as expected save a minor anomaly. It prints the prompt message after taking an input number from the user resulting in an output like:

```
12
Enter the number of prime numbers to display: [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37]
```

Why is Haskell not sequencing the IO actions correctly? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This looks more like a buffering than a sequencing problem.  What platform are you on?  Have you tried forcing unbuffered output?

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- from System.IO
```

Comment: I'm using the Glasgow Haskell Compiler. Thank you. That was indeed the problem. I need to learn more about IO operations in Haskell.

Comment: By platform I meant more like OS and terminal.  Usually, stdin and stdout are "tied" in a way that makes stdout flush whenever stdin is read from, precisely to avoid that sort of problem.  FWIW, your problem both buffers and sequences properly on my setup.

Comment: Oh, I'm using the "Terminal" on Ubuntu 13.10. I'm not really sure whether it has a specific name like xterm but it's the same terminal found on a Macintosh OSX.

Comment: **Edit:** I have the same "untied" behavior using Debian and LXTerminal or gnome-terminal. [The C people seem to agree that there isn't an automatic flush](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528/does-reading-from-stdin-flush-stdout)

Comment: The tie thing is [more of a C++ thing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/). I can't seem to find an authoritative mention of this about Haskell of GHC, so it's reasonable to assume there's no such thing here either. My setup (GHCi in emacs) is ultra-biased.

Answer (score 11):

`stdin` and `stdout` are two different files that needn't have any connection. Take e.g. the Unix shell command `grep`:

```
$ seq 1 100 | grep 2$ | less
```

`seq 1 100` prints the numbers 1 to 100 to its `stdout` which is `grep`s `stdin` (`|` connects the `stdout` of one command to the `stdin` of an other). `grep` then writes the lines that match the given regex to its `stdout` which is `less`s `stdin`.

To force `stdout` (or any other file) to be written use `hFlush` from `System.IO`:

```
 hFlush stdout
```