# Why does scanf ask for input in the very beginning?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a very simple program that simply asks for ones weight and converts it to the value of platinum.  I am new to C so the mistake could be anywhere.  But when I use scanf, it asks for input at the very beginning rather than following the sequence of code:

code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
     float weight;
     float value;

     printf("Are you worth your weight in platinum?\n");
     printf("Let's check it out.\n");
     printf("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
     scanf("%f", &weight);
     printf("%.2f\n", weight);
     value = 1700.0 * weight * 14.5833;
     printf("Your weight in platinum is worth $%.2f.\n", value);
     printf("You are easily worth that! If platinum prices drop,\n");
     printf("eat more to maintain your value.\n");

     return 0;

 }
```

Output:

```
123
Are you worth your weight in platinum?
Let's check it out.
Please enter your weight in pounds: 123.00
Your weight in platinum is worth $3049368.00.
You are easily worth that! If platinum prices drop,
eat more to maintain your value.
```

If you notice in the output the user has to enter input before the first line prints. Why is this?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you 100% sure the code you're running is the one we see?

Comment: Are you redirecting the output to a file or pipe, by any chance?  Usually, that's a problem with buffering, but when the input and output are a terminal, the standard I/O library normally flushes stdout before reading from stdin, so it normally just works.  However, if the writing is going to a pipe or file, then what you're seeing is more nearly normal.  Also, is there a reason pure C code is tagged as C++?  C++ uses `<iostream>` etc for preference.  This should, presumably does, also compile as C++, but it is using legacy C features rather than C++ features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your program and it worked as you want for me. You might try flushing the `stdout` buffer before you scan for input.

```
fflush(stdout); // right before your scanf line.
```

The OS is free to postpone writing output buffers for efficiency. So, for instance, you write to the disk in blocks instead of one character at a time. fflush forces the buffer to be written. It's "endl" in C++ and fflush is the straight c version. I'm not certain that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Cool. You don't want to add flush everywhere now. It's only when you want to insist that you get all the output. Generally, postponing writing buffers is a good thing.

Comment: `stdout` should be flushed automatically when the program prints a newline. So only the line `Please enter...` should need an explicit flush. Can you explain why the other lines aren't being shown until he enters something?

Comment: I think it's very much an implementation-dependent thing. @BlankQQ's example worked just as (s)he wanted on my machine. There is a more extensive discussion of the question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528/does-reading-from-stdin-flush-stdout) It seems that implementations often flush stdout when writing to the terminal output, but it's not guaranteed.